# Javascript Controller Loading/unloading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Most of these questions don't have very comprehensive answers.

say in my application, i've decided to call whatever controller is currently loaded something like `$app.ctrl`

now when i set `$app.ctrl` to null, what about any events that controller created?

for instance, my app might load a controller like this:

```
loadController : function(controller){
    $app.ctrl = null;
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('src', $app.ctrl_path+controller);
    s.className = 'ctrl';
    s.onload= function(){
        $app.ctrl = $ctrl;
        $app.ctrl.initialize();
    };
    document.body.appendChild( s );
},
```

How will events and instantiated plugins be cleaned up? what if my controller does lots of nasty stuff with jQuery plugins and adding event listeners and sech?
Will GC really destroy these events, or will they secretly remain lurking, waiting to cause havoc: (suprise, they do)

```
var $ctrl = {

    initialize : function(){
        $(window).on('resize',function(){
            alert('you resized');
        });
    }

};
```

So what's the solution here? should my `$app` object define setters and getters for events, and a clean method for controllers? then the controller defiles a list targets and their events? so confused.

I think its pathetic that in 2015 javascript is this worthless in every modern browser.

Comment: The solution is to have and call `deinitialize` function.  I don't see how it's "pathetic".

Comment: @kyrylkov its completely pathetic, how could you arrive at any other conclusion? i guess you enjoy writing millions of lines of boilerplate code for no reason other than the language was designed poorly

Comment: You're talking about a library here, not a language.

Comment: @kyrylkov this has nothing to do with jQuery i just used it to illustrate the flaw of loading and unloading scripts, and how much needless work is created due to poor design choices.

Comment: Cleaning up event handlers is not the job of GC.

Comment: if a script is removed, the events, objects, variables, etc it created should also be removed. this is 2015.

Comment: And you can cite any example of other language where it's done by GC (not as "pathetic" as JavaScript)?

Comment: @kyrylkov can you cite any other language where you would want to dynamically load and unload code from the runtime?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87681/discussion-between-kyrylkov-and-r3wt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to have and call de-initialize function with `.off()`:

reference:

https://api.jquery.com/off/